# Color theme doesnt apply

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-idea

i've been using VS-Code for years now. And i've been loving the One Dark Italic theme.

Now i've switched to IJ. And the first thing, i did, was installing the theme... however. It is not working correctly.

[Code in IJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9rpT.png)

It should look like this
[Code in VS-Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP2Ax.png)

Anyone who can help?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reinstall the IDE. You can save the config file, to keep your settings.
If you dont know how, here is the link (for windows and linux)
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs